# How do I configure visual studio to use the code view as the default view for Webservices?

Tags: visual-studio, web-services

When you double click on a class (in 'solution explorer')... if that class happens to be an .asmx.cs webservice... then you get this...

> To add components to your class, drag
>   them from the Toolbox and use
>   the Properties window to set their
>   properties. To create methods and
>   events for your class, click here
>   to switch to code view.

...it's a 'visual design surface' for webservices.

(Who actually uses that surface to write webservices?)

So what I want to know, how do I configure visual studio to never show me that design view?

Or at least, to show me the code view by default?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can set the default editor for any given file type (.cs, .xml, .xsd, etc).  To change the default editor for a given type:

1. Right-click a file of that type in
   your project, and select "Open
   With..."
2. Select your preferred editor. You
   may want "CSharp Editor".
3. Click "Set as Default".

I don't see the behavior you see with web services, but this should work with all file types in Visual Studio.

Comment: This worked for me.  Now those pesky "let's make it a Component, because Components!" classes like those deriving from ServiceBase don't open up in a useless designer.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following attribute to your class:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("Code")]
```

(Not sure why [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("")] does not work.)

Comment: Just discovered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/567606/disable-designer-in-visual-studio which has a better discussion of this.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following attribute to your class:

```
<System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("")>
```

Comment: I was the upvoter 'cause it looked like it would work and Andrew Borys's response. But now I've actually tried it and found it doesn't work for me in VS2k8 for a general class inherted from Component. I am yet to try it for a web service as this question is specifically about, but I'd remove my upvote if I could :-(