# Disable designer in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I'm using Visual C# Express to write Windows Form applications, and call me old school, but I don't like the designer. It is a nuisance and pollutes my project with lots of unwanted files, as well as unwanted monkey-generated source code.

Please tell me there's a way to turn it off completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just **dont add "new form"** , add to the project new class and inherit him from the Form class.

Comment: I think this answer just changed my life. I can now write C++/CLI form applications the same way I would normally write Java, without having to use C#. I never thought of using C++/CLI without designer before, but it's beautifully powerful.

Answer (score 105):

Add a `[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("")]` attribute before a UI class to avoid designer activation on double-click.

Note that including `System.ComponentModel` at the top of the file and then just adding the attribute as `[DesignerCategory("")]` will not work (at least not in Visual Studio 2010/2013). You must use the full, namespace-qualified attribute type name.

Comment: You also seem to have to remove "<SubType>Form</SubType>" from the file's entry in the project file (e.g. .csproj file), at least in VS 2010

Comment: I echo the comments from @wizlb for VS2012

Comment: In VS2013, it was "<SubType>Component</SubType>" rather than form, but Matt's point is correct. Nothing will happen otherwise.

Comment: But how to enable designer for derived class? For example, I have 


[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("")]
class MyUserControl : UserControl{}


and 


class MyDerivedFromMyUserControl: MyUserControl{}


Is it possible to make first one non-designable, but make second one designable?

Comment: Set the [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("Component")] attribute

Comment: This is nice in that it works across teams and across reinstallations.

Comment: Looks like just setting [DesignerCategory("")] in VS2015 is sufficient.  Hooray!

Comment: Works also great with VS 2015.

Comment: Works like a charm in VS17. This should have been the accepted answer.

Comment: I do not like using "", used null instead and it's working!

[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory(null)]

Answer (score 30):

Right clicking on a project file and selecting open with allows you to set the defaults for opening file types.

Comment: OK, thanks, that's a big help. I didn't realize I could set the default opener for a file. It was a small nuisance to right click and pick "view code" every time.

Comment: This just showed me how to get rid of the SQL Design view stuff in Visual Studio 2012 and set it back to just opening it with a T-SQL Editor. Thanks, Richard from the past!

Comment: That's right but be careful. If you open the designer by accident, then it might mess up yourhandwritten code.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, all you have to do in VS2010 is right click the .cs file that you *don't* want to open in the designer, select the "Open With.." option, then make CSharp Editor the default. Notice that the form view is the default before you change it.

Comment: That's right, but then you could still accidentally open up the designer. I have a form where I strictly **must** prohibit invocation of the designer, because the designer is messing up the code.

Answer (score 2):

Frederik,
sure you're right, but not in one fact. ( this one I.J wanted to know )
As soon as you inherit from any Component, the studio tries to open it in a designer editor. That is a default behaviour of the visual studio.

If you double click a file in the solution explorer, then a designer opens.
So it's really annoying if you always get such strange designer for classes that are just inherited from a Component, but do not contain any visible things.

The only thing that really helped me out, was to set this attribute:[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("")]

I didn't knew this =) so cool hint !

I just get a problem with partial MainForm classes. Then it yells "duplicate attribute"...

Does here anybody knows a solution to avoid in some partial class-files the designer to be opened on double click ( without the duplicate attribute error on compile ? )

---

I think I found a small bug, in VS2005...
By setting the DesignerCategory-Attribute on the partial form class, on save the solution explorer shows up an icon, identifying the file as a c# file (no form).

Then I put a comment (//) before the attribute - and it keeps opening the file in code view. Also after closing and reopening it's stored internally as a non designable form-part.
Even on re opening the complete solution.

So I think there is any information in the solution or project file...

... I found this in the .csproj file:
...

```
<Compile Include="GUI\VFormMain_Test.cs">
</Compile>
<Compile Include="GUI\VFormMain_Theme.cs">
</Compile>
<Compile Include="Core\VTTEnv.cs" />
<Compile Include="GUI\VFormMain.cs">
  <SubType>form</SubType>
</Compile>
```

...

Studio updates from time to time - then it updated the form files again (doh)... ok.. but there is probably a workaround to avoid this.

---

snip...
last edit...
found something:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpide/thread/64c77755-b0c1-4447-8ac9-b5a63a681b78

( name the file you want to open without designer into .Designer.cs )

( Yes you have to name something to switch it of LOL )
Seems to work.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to use the designer, then don't use it ?

You can create a new form from scratch, without the designer generating any code by creating a new empty class, and let the class inherit from `System.Windows.Forms.Form`

Then, VS.NET will probably still indicate that your class is a Form, and you can still open it up in the designer if you want.  (And drop controls on it).

Comment: The problem is when it opens by default every time you open a specific file type.