# Class always tries to open in Design View, not Code View

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, design-view

I have a class named `Print.cs` that always stubbornly opens in Design View, when I need to see its Code View (<kbd>F7</kbd>). It also has a different icon to the rest of my classes in the Solution Explorer.

I've looked in the Properties and can't see anything relevant. I've also tried deleting and re-creating the class, but the icon comes back.

How can I force `Print.cs` to always open in Code View?

<sub>**(Click to enlarge)**</sub>

[image]

NB: disregard the green squiggly line, it's just a warning that unreachable code was detected.

Comment: Can you show the definition of the class? I guess it is inheriting from Component or something like that

Comment: @Juan Sure, it's `public class Print : PrintDocument {...}`

Comment: So yes, it inherits from Component... so not sure if you can avoid that. Maybe instead of extending PrintDocument you can try to do some composition instead?

Comment: See [Disable designer in Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/602589/719186).  Ignore the accepted answer, read the second paragraph of the highest voted answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Taken from the suggestions from @LarsTech and @OrkunBekar, since neither posted this as an answer - this works:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("Code")]
```

Added between the namespace and the class, e.g.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
...

namespace POS
{

    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("Code")]

    public class Print : PrintDocument
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: As a side note after you open the file once you can remove the decoration from the class and it will still open up in code view.  At least I could.

Comment: @Chad I cannot confirm this behavior. It opened properly at first. But then sometimes later it stopped working and I had to add [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("Code")] again.

Answer (score 8):

Try right click on the file -> `Open With` -> `CSharp Editor` (remember to set it as default).

Answer (score 2):

Funny enough, it was totally other thing in my case.
If the filename equal (=) to the first class in it, then Visual Studio decides it is a simple C# file. If you have 2 classes and the first is not equal to the file name, then the solution icon changes and default editor is designer.
[image: Visual Studio]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you have same conditions in that [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880589/vs2010-opens-my-class-file-cs-in-the-designer-mode) but opening your class in notepad, changing codes, replacing file then building the solution again may fix the problem.